# how to only show business hours in react FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have this code which is the code for setting paramaters for my calendar:

```
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'

calevents.push({
        title: res.data[i].title, 
        start: moment(res.data[i].dateTime).toDate(), 
        end: moment(res.data[i].dateTime).add(2, 'hours'), 
        displayEventEnd: true, 
        id: res.data[i]._id, 
        allDayDefault: false,
        slotMinTime: '8:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '18:00:00',
          extendedProps: {
            description: res.data[i].description
          },
      })
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is set the `business hours` of my business for the calendar. Using `slotMinTime` and `slotMaxTime` I thought I could set it, however, it doesn't change the view of the calendar.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You seem to be adding the slotMinTime and slotMaxTime to an individual event, not to the calendar settings. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react (if you're using the React fullcalendar component) shows you how to set calendar-wide options (see the "Props" section of the docs). Also bear in mind that of course the slot time options only apply to time-aware views such as timeGrid or timeline (and not, for example, to the dayGridMonth view which has no concept of times, it only works in whole days).

Comment: thanks for your help, this totally made sense. I did infact fix it by putting it directly within the calendar.